# Do macros run faster than global variables in C? How to change macros between runs?

Tags: c, macros

I'm writing a program in C in which there are several constants I would like all of my functions to use. So far, I have used macros. A simplified version of the program looks as follows.

```
#define CONSTANT 10 //int
int multiplication_by_constant(int a){ return a*CONSTANT;}
int main(){
   for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
       printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
}
```

Now I want to run experiments on the program by running it several times with different values of the constant. I want to automate this, and not re-compile each time I change CONSTANT. I used a simple solution by changing the macros to global variables, putting the original main function into a new 'program()' function, then to run the experiments in the main file, i.e.

```
int CONSTANT =  10; //int
int multiplication_by_constant(int a){ return a*CONSTANT;}
void program(){
   for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
       printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
}
int main(){
   while(CONSTANT < 100){
       program();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I discovered that this implementation lead to quite a substantial loss of performance of the loop

```
for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
       printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
```

which now requires around 50% more run time than when I was using the macro. Is this normal?

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way for me to run my experiment?

PS In C++, I would do this by defining a 'class program', setting CONSTANT to be a class member and 'multiplication_by_constant' a member function. I could then easily run the experiments through 'main' using the class definition, and I think I wouldn't have the efficiency loss... I have to use C in this implementation which is why I've resorted to the global variables and functions.

Comment: doesn't make much sense. macros are evaluated at compile time. there's no "macros" once you have a binary executable and are executing that.

Comment: How are you gathering your statistics?  What profiling techniques are you using?

Comment: @JohnBode I use 'gettimeofday' before and after the 'for' loop to calculate the elapsed time

Comment: @Plamen: How many runs are you averaging over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's a *potential* source of the performance difference.  With a macro, the value of `CONSTANT` is known at *compile time*, so the compiler can take advantage of that knowledge and structure the machine code a little differently.  I took a variation of your code and used `gcc -Wa,-aldh` to get an assembly listing<sup>1</sup> for both the macro and global variable versions, with an interesting difference.

First is the macro version:

```
 3                    .globl mul_by_const
 5                    mul_by_const:
 6                    .LFB2:
 7 0000 55                    pushq   %rbp
 8                    .LCFI0:
 9 0001 4889E5                movq    %rsp, %rbp
10                    .LCFI1:
11 0004 897DFC                movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
12 0007 8B55FC                movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
13 000a 89D0                  movl    %edx, %eax
14 000c C1E002                sall    $2, %eax
15 000f 01D0                  addl    %edx, %eax
16 0011 01C0                  addl    %eax, %eax
17 0013 C9                    leave
18 0014 C3                    ret
```

The highlighted lines are the meat of the function; instead of multiplying the value in `%eax` by 10, the function does an arithmetic shift left by 2 places followed by an addition (effectively multiplying by 5), and then adds the result to itself.  For example, given an `i` value of `3`:

```
 3 << 2 == 12
 3 + 12 == 15
15 + 15 == 30
```

If you change the value of `CONSTANT`, the compiler will generate different machine code (a `CONSTANT` value of `7` results in an arithmetic shift left by 3 followed by a subtraction, while a value of `19` gives a left shift of 3 followed by 3 additions, etc).

Compare that with the global variable version:

```
 2                    .globl CONSTANT
 3                            .data
 4                            .align 4
 7                    CONSTANT:
 8 0000 0A000000              .long   10
 9                            .text
10                    .globl mul_by_const
12                    mul_by_const:
13                    .LFB2:
14 0000 55                    pushq   %rbp
15                    .LCFI0:
16 0001 4889E5                movq    %rsp, %rbp
17                    .LCFI1:
18 0004 897DFC                movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
19 0007 8B050000              movl    CONSTANT(%rip), %eax
19      0000
20 000d 0FAF45FC              imull   -4(%rbp), %eax
21 0011 C9                    leave
22 0012 C3                    ret
```

This version uses the `imull` opcode to do the multiplication.  Since the value of `CONSTANT` isn't known at compile time, the compiler can't do any special optimizations based on that value.

Now, this is how things shake out on *my particular platform*; I don't know what compiler you're using or what OS you're running on, so it's likely that the machine code you're getting is different from what I have above.  I'm just pointing out that knowing `CONSTANT` at compile time allows the compiler to do some extra optimization.

**Edit**

If you change the value of a macro, you *have* to recompile.  You could put the macro in a header file, and then write a script to regenerate the header and recompile, something like

```
#!/bin/bash

let CONSTANT=1
while [ $CONSTANT -lt 20 ]
do
  cat > const.h << EOF
#ifndef CONST_H
#define CONST_H
#define CONSTANT $CONSTANT
#endif
EOF
  # build and run your test code, assuming profiling is captured
  # automatically
  gcc -o test test.c
  ./test
  let CONSTANT=CONSTANT+1
done
```

and your C code would `#include` the const.h file:

```
#include "const.h"
int multiplication_by_constant(int a){ return a*CONSTANT;}
...
```

---

<sup>1. Platform is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64), compiler is gcc 4.1.2</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Macros don't "run", exactly. A macro is an instruction to the C preprocessor, which effectively replaces uses of the macro with the definition of the macro before passing it on to the compiler. Whether a given macro or function call is more efficient is dependent on the macro and the function call. In your example, as John Bode shows in his answer, having the macro represent a literal is advantageous over using a variable. In general there is no inherent difference between expressing *the same code* inline vs as a macro. A more efficiently coded inline statement will be more efficient then a less efficiently coded macro.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely correct.  That last sentence is wrong.  The macro is replaced during preprocessing.  The compiler just sees the function call, not the macro, so there is no difference at run time between a function call defined by a macro which is replaced and the bare function call.

Comment: "If the macro is a *less efficient function call*," e.g. a call to a less efficient function or a call to the same function in a less efficient manner, then it will be less efficient than the bare function call. I stand by my logic, if not my clarity.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not quite understanding what the preprocessor does. Think of macros as search-and-replace templates, i.e. your small program

```
#define CONSTANT 10 //int
int multiplication_by_constant(int a){ return a*CONSTANT; }
int main(){
   for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
       printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
}
```

Is equivalent to writing

```
int multiplication_by_constant(int a){ return a*10; }
int main(){
   for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
       printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
}
```

In this, there is no field to read before multiplying the input value, which would account for the speedup.

Try running just the preprocessor and compare the output of your two variants, and if you really are running just these small programs (and the above is not a distilled version of your actual problem), you could try comparing the assembler output as well. If nothing else, you will get a better understanding of whatever toolchain you are using :-)

Comment: `cpp <your_file.c>` should output the file after being preprocessed. You can then see that there are no differenced between the two versions after they've been compiled.

Comment: I see, that's quite obvious now. I guess this means there's no hope to automate the experiments in one C program without the efficiency loss. Is there any way to automate the macro definition? E.g. could I write a script to compile the C with a new definition for CONSTANT?

Comment: Precisely! All compilers that I know of accept macro definitions as command-line parameters, just be aware that they can't override anything specified in source.

Answer (score 1):

C programs are built in steps.  Those steps are as follows:

1. Preprocessing: (macros, includes, defines, etc...) Basically anything that starts with a # symbol is taken care of here.
2. Compilation: The preprocessed C source is translated (compiled) into assembler.
3. Assembly: The assembler translates the assembly source file (generated through compilation) into a machine object code file.
4. Linking: The final step resolves external references to libraries and generates a runnable program.

Armed with this knowledge, the macro is processed in the preprocessing stage.  In your case, everywhere CONSTANT shows up in the source is replaced by 10.  So to change the constant, you have to change the #define statement and recompile.  Since CONSTANT is replaced with the actual number 10, it is considered an immediate value.  But if you want to change it during run time, you have to use a variable as there is no other way of getting around it.

One thing you could do, however, is change this line:

```
 printf("%d\n",multiplication_by_constant(i));
```

To this:

```
 printf("%d\n",i * CONSTANT);
```

This way you avoid the function call entirely and remove the overhead associated with making that function call.